# Faster alternative to Java Robot Class

Tags: java, video, streaming, frame-rate, awtrobot

I googled a lot, and I've seen similar question on stack but I wasn't able to find anything useful (working with JNI or OpenCV), so here I am:

I'm developing a simple streaming video application (with Xuggler Library) that has to perform lots of screen capture. I tried  with Java Robot class but 120ms to take a screenshot (2800x1800) I think is quite a lot, so how can I improve it to have a frame rate of at least 40 fps?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe something like https://code.google.com/p/java-screen-recorder/ would help you get started.

Comment: I don't want to use ffmpeg or stuff like that :/

Comment: It doesn't use ffmpeg... it just says that you can use ffmpeg to convert to other formats